# Finite differences for 2D Parabolic PDE

Tags: math, fortran, fortran90, gfortran, differential-equations

This is a modified problem from Numerical Computing-Kincaid's book, chapter 15. (not physics)

How can I properly implement the boundary conditions? The conditions are

```
u(0,y,t) = u(x,0,t) = u(nx,y,t) = u(x,ny,t) = 0.
```

I am not doing it correctly, it seems.  My code is below.

I am trying to write a Fortran code to solve the 2D heat (parabolic) equation using Finite Differences.  When I print out my results, I get divergent results and 'NaN'.  It seems I am not defining the boundary conditions correctly.  I properly did the code in 1 dimension, trying to generalize it in two I have troubles at the boundary.

Note, `i,j` are for the x and y position do loops respectively, m is for time do loop.  `nx,ny,W` are the number of grid points in x , y direction and time  respectively.   `Lx,Ly` and `tmax` are the size of the position and time intervals for the mesh.  The position(x,y) steps and time steps are given by `hx,hy,k` respectively, and `hx` and `hy` are equal for the example below.  I store my solutions in the variables u and v as shown below.

```
program parabolic2D

implicit none

integer :: i,j,m 
integer, parameter :: nx=10., ny=10., W=21. 
real, parameter :: Lx=1.0, Ly=1.0, tmax=0.1 
real :: hx,hy,k,pi,pi2,R,t 
real, dimension (0:nx,0:ny) :: u,v 


hx=(Lx-0.0)/nx 
hy=(Ly-0.0)/ny 
k=(tmax-0.0)/W
R=k/hx**2.
u(0,0)=0.0; v(0,0)=0.0; u(nx,ny)=0.0; v(nx,ny)=0.0 !boundary conditions u(0,0,t)=0=u(nx,ny,t)
pi=4.0*atan(1.0) 
pi2=pi*pi



do i=1,nx-1
do j=1,ny-1
u(i,j)=sin(pi*real(i)*hx)*sin(pi*real(j)*hy)  !initial condition
end do
end do

do m=1,W

do i=1,nx-1
do j=1,ny-1
v(i,j) = R*(u(i+1,j)+u(i-1,j)+u(i,j+1)+u(i,j-1))+(1-4*R)*u(i,j) !Discretization for u(x,y,t+k)
end do
end do

t = real(m)*k ! t refers to time in the problem.

do i=1,nx-1
do j=1,ny-1
u(i,j)=v(i,j) !redefining variables.
end do
end do
write(*,*) 'for all times m, this prints out u(x,y,t)',m,((u(i,j),i=0,nx),j=0,ny)

end do

end program parabolic2D
```

Comment: We don't really solve physics problems here, sorry. If you have a specific coding problem we can probably help, but this type of problem is probably out-of-scope for stackoverflow.

Comment: With that said, I'm able to offer a couple questions that may help guide you on your way. Are you sure you're setting your boundary conditions correctly? It looks like you're only setting u(0,0) and u(nx,ny), but then using u(0,1:ny-1), for example.

Comment: Also, because it looks like you're trying to learn, I recommend you indent your code. It's very difficult to read improperly formatted code, and indenting for loops and conditionals is a key part of that.

Comment: From Joe: thanks for your comments below. I cannot reply back because I do not have a rating of >50.  How do you suggest I fix the boundary conditions?  I do not understand your comment, when you say "but then using `u(0,1:ny-1)`,".   I am trying to learn Fortran.

Comment: @Joe You can always comment under your own questions, you don't need any rep. More importantly, this question belongs elsewhere. Best to http://scicomp.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Ross points out, you haven't fully specified the boundary conditions for the edges `i=j=0` and `i=nx` and `j=nx`. Only the corners of your domain have bee specified.

Change

`u(0,0)=0.0; v(0,0)=0.0; u(nx,ny)=0.0; v(nx,ny)=0.0 !boundary conditions u(0,0,t)=0=u(nx,ny,t)`

to

`u(0,:)=0.0
u(nx,:)=0.0
u(:,0)=0.0
u(:,ny)=0.0`

or even

`u=0.0`.

The interior points are overwritten later.